# Move Outlook Favourite Folder Item up in list with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am writing an outlook script in VBA to take an inbox from multiple mailboxes and add them all to my favourites.

my favourites folder may have pre-existing folders inside of it and I want to make sure these new folders I am adding are at the top of the list.

WHen I add the folder, it appears at the bottom. I can use the Outlook GUI eventually move the item up to the top (right click on folder for options and click 'move up').

How can I do this using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you said the problem is a sorting problem. Unfortunately, sorting algorithm can only be their own implementation, there is no ready-made available. You could refer to the following link:

[MAPI Provider Sorting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2013/11/08/mapi-provider-sorting/)